# Redundancy in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, programming-languages

Take the following snippet:

```
List<int> distances = new List<int>();
```

Was the redundancy intended by the language designers? If so, why?

Comment: This is really not an ok question.

Comment: @Rich: No, I'm just trying to learn about language design. But, whatever.

Comment: @Esteban: You worded this as flamebait.

Comment: A valid question, for sure, but definitely worded in a flamebait-ish tone.

Comment: @Rich: Perhaps, but highly subjective. However, you can't say the question is offtopic. It's definitely about programming.

Comment: I'll edit to reduce flamebaitness.

Comment: And there I was hoping that someone is interested in redundant system design...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The reason the code appears to be redundant is because, to a novice programmer, it appears to be defining the same thing twice. But this is not what the code is doing. It is defining two separate things that just happen to be of the same type. It is defining the following:

1. A variable named distances of type `List<int>`.
2. An object on the heap of type `List<int>`.

Consider the following:

```
Person[] coworkers = new Employee[20];
```

Here the non-redundancy is clearer, because the variable and the allocated object are of two different types (a situation that is legal if the object’s type derives from or implements the variable’s type).

Comment: @Jeffrey - nicely put. May want to edit and include that Employee inherits from Person to help clarify your explanation. Otherwise, some may think that Employee[] emp = new Person[] is valid. Well, it could be, but who knows :-)

Comment: I just noticed someone down-vote this answer and I'm curious as to why.  It seems straightforward and accurate to me - am I missing something?

Comment: Collections are not a great example, because the fact that you can do this with arrays is actually considered a flaw in the language design. The reason being that the compiler will let you store a non-Employee, Person-derived object in the collection, but this will fail at runtime.

Comment: The questioner used a collection in the example, and I just went with it. I went with an array though, because generics are not covariant or contravariant in C# (at least, not yet). Whether the C# implementation of an array is flawed or not, it satisfied the purpose of the example.

Comment: Yeah, it could just have easily used List<Person> p = new List<Employee>();

Answer (score 15):

What's redudant about this?

```
List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>():
```

Translated to English: (EDIT, cleaned up a little for clarification)

- Create a pointer of type List<int> and name it listofInts.
- listOfInts is now created but its just a reference pointer pointing to nowhere (null)
- Now, create an object of type List<int> on the heap, and return the pointer to listOfInts.
- Now listOfInts points to a List<int> on the heap.

Not really verbose when you think about what it does.

Of course there is an alternative:

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

Here we are using C#'s type inference, because you are assigning to it immediately, C# can figure out what type you want to create by the object just created in the heap.

To fully understand how the CLR handles types, I recommend reading [CLR Via C#](http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/6522.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

You could always say:

```
 var distances = new List<int>();
```

Comment: You could, but you should not! The var keyword is designed for the case where the designer does not know the type that is returned, but the compiler does - as with dynamic types in linq. It is NOT  designed for lazy programmers.

Comment: Leveraging type inference is not about being lazy.

Comment: Or, embrace type inference. It's a feature, and it's there for you to use. At least, that's the case in all *other* languages sporting type inference. Also, linq does not have "dynamic types". It embraces a non-linq feature called "compiler-generated static anonymous types".

Comment: i think he meant anonymous types. but ive read a ms paper where they say not to use var in this situation. i still do when i find its more readable, like in this situation

Comment: I will always use var in this situation! The type of the object is very clear from the context at the call site. However, I would refrain from using var when calling a function that retuns the same type, as the return value is not always clear to the reader.

Answer (score 10):

As others have said: `var` removes the redundancy, but it has *potential* negative maintenance consequences. I'd say it also has potential *positive* maintenance consequences.

Fortunately Eric Lippert writes about it a lot more eloquently than I do:
http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=63
http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=61

Answer (score 4):

Because declaring a type doesn't necessarily have anything to do with initializing it.

I can declare

```
List<int> foo;
```

and leave it to be initialized later.  Where's the redundancy then?  Maybe it receives the value from another function like BuildList().

As others have mentioned the new var keyword lets you get around that, but you *have* to initialize the variable at declaration so that the compiler can tell what type it is.

Answer (score 4):

instead of thinking of it as redundant, think of that construct as a feature to allow you to save a line.

instead of having

List distances;
distances = new List();

c# lets you put them on one line.

One line says "I will be using a variable called *distances*, and it will be of type List."  Another line says "Allocate a new List and call the parameterless constructor".

Is that too redundant?  Perhaps. doing it this way gives you some things, though

**1**. Separates out the variable declaration from object allocation.  Allowing:

```
IEnumerable<int> distances = new List<int>();
// or more likely...
IEnumerable<int> distances = GetList();
```

**2.** It allows for more strong static type checking by the compiler - giving compiler errors when your declarations don't match the assignments, rather than runtime errors.

Are both of these required for writing software?  No.  There are plenty of languages that don't do this, and/or differ on many other points.

*"Doctor! it hurts when I do this!" - "Don't do that anymore"*

If you find that you don't need or want the things that c# gives you, try other languages.  Even if you don't use them, knowing other ones can give you a huge boost in how you approach problems. If you do use one, great!

Either way, you may find enough perspective to allow yourself to say "I don't need the strict static type checking enforced by the c# compiler.  I'll use python", rather than flaming c# as too redundant.

Comment: I suspect the poster's point wasn't about requiring type specification on variable declarations, but rather requiring them when the information is the same.  This is a fair criticism, and one that the language designers took to heart in creating the "var" keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Could also do:

```
var distances = new List<int>();
```

Comment: You could, but you should not! The var keyword is designed for the case where the designer does not know the type that is returned, but the compiler does - as with dynamic types in linq. It is NOT designed for lazy programmers.

Comment: No you are wrong. Where the type is obvious, it's ok to use the var, as is the case here.

Do you really need to see List<int> twice?

Comment: Actually read the msdn C# programming guide. The use of var to remove redundancy is suggested. And the lazy principle is a fundamental of programming. Why waste your time saying the same thing twice. It just costs your employer money.

Comment: Why is this being flagged as offensive?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler improvements for C# 3.0 (which corresponds with .Net 3.5) eliminate some of this sort of thing.  So your code can now be written as:

```
var distances = new List<int>();
```

The updated compiler is much better at figuring out types based on additional information in the statement.  That means that there are fewer instances where you need to specify a type either for an assignment, or as part of a Generic.

That being said, there are still some areas which could be improved.  Some of that is API and some is simply due to the restrictions of strong typing.

Comment: You could, but you should not! The var keyword is designed for the case where the designer does not know the type that is returned, but the compiler does - as with dynamic types in linq. It is NOT designed for lazy programmers.

Answer (score 2):

The redunancy wasn't intended, per se, but was a side-effect of the fact that all variables and fields needed to have a type declaration. When you take into account that all object instantiations also mention the type's name in a *new* expression, you get redundant looking statements.

Now with type-inferencing using the **var** keyword, that redundancy can be eliminated. The compiler is smart enough to figure it out. The next C++ also has an **auto** keyword that does the same thing.

The main reason they introduced **var**, though, was for anonymous types, which have no name:

```
var x = new {Foo = Bar, Number = 1};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's only "redundant" if you are comparing it to dynamically typed languages.  It's useful for polymorphism and finding bugs at compile time.  Also, it makes code auto-complete/intellisense easier for your IDE (if you use one).

Answer (score 1):

C# is definitely getting less verbose after the addition of functional support.

Answer (score 1):

A historical artifact of static typing / C syntax; compare the Ruby example:

```
distances = []
```

Comment: Struggling a bit isn't it? "var"!? "new"!? ";"!?

Comment: Whats the ruby equivalent of creating a abstract type from a concrete constructor?

Comment: Ruby doesn't care about types in that way, Jonathan. It's a simple "x = SomeClass.new".

Answer (score 1):

Use var if it is obvious what the type is to the reader.

```
//Use var here
var names = new List<string>();

//but not here
List<string> names = GetNames();
```

From microsofts [C# programing guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

> The var keyword can also be useful
>   when the specific type of the variable
>   is tedious to type on the keyboard, or
>   is obvious, or does not add to the
>   readability of the code

Comment: Please do not, as var is not designed for code complifications, but for struggling with dynamic types of linq.

Comment: BeowulfOF see my edit this use of var is suggested by microsoft in there C# programming guide.

Comment: Exactly my point. Please be considerate before voting people down without knowing the finer details.

Comment: Well, it reads "or does not add to the readability of the code" - so theres the point to not do that.

Comment: If for some reason you're nesting multiple generic collections, like var lotsOfLists = new List<List<List<List<int>>>>();, it is certainly more readable than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular example is indeed a bit verbose but in most ways C# is rather lean.

I'd much prefer this (C#)

```
int i;
```

to this (VB.NET)

```
Dim i as Integer
```

Now, the particular example you chose is something about .NET in general which is a bit on the long side, but I don't think that's C#'s fault. Maybe the question should be rephrased "Why is .NET code so verbose?"

Answer (score 0):

I see one other problem with the using of var for laziness like that

```
var names = new List<string>();
```

If you use var, the variable named "names" is typed as `List<string>,` but you would eventually only use one of the interfaces inherited by `List<T>.`

```
IList<string> = new List<string>();
ICollection<string> = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<string> = new List<string>();
```

You can automatically use everything of that, but can you consider what interface you wanted to use at the time you wrote the code?

The var keyword does not improve readability in this example.

Answer (score 0):

In many of the answers to this question, the authors are thinking like compilers or apologists. An important rule of good programming is **Don't repeat yourself!**

Avoiding this unnecessary repetition is an [explicit design goal](http://golang.org/doc/go_lang_faq.html#principles) of Go, for example:

> Stuttering (`foo.Foo* myFoo = new(foo.Foo)`) is reduced by simple type derivation using the `:=` declare-and-initialize construct.

Answer (score -1):

Because we're addicted to compilers and compiler errors.