# C# redundancy, noise

Tags: c#

EDIT 1: This question is about new features of C#, not about actual possibilities (where there is no such thing as `new default()`).

EDIT 2: [There is actually a discussion about that reduction of redundancy @ .DOTNET Foundation.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100)

When declaring a member,

```cs
class MyClass {

    AnyClass<WithLong<Generic,Declaration>> value = 
        new AnyClass<WithLong<Generic,Declaration>>();

}
```

is quite redundant.

We may find the following, more concise, less noisy:

```cs
AnyClass<WithLong<Generic,Declaration>> value = new default();
// or
AnyClass<WithLong<Generic,Declaration>> value = new();
// or
AnyClass<WithLong<Generic,Declaration>> value = new var();
```

Is there any benefit to the actual redundancy, or any risk on a more concise declaration that I haven't identified ?

Note 1:
`var` is actually a good way to reduce noise :

```cs
var value = new AnyClass<WithLong<Generic,Declaration>>();
```

My comment is about extending that concision to members.

Note 2:
[A similar question has already been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137448/redundancy-in-c), but answers don't really care about redundancy & noise, which is unfortunate, because i think keywords like `default`, `var` are already intended to reduce code noise, and that is not a so futile question.

Comment: `new default()` is not valid C# in C# 7.3.

Comment: @aloisdg C# 9.0 isn't anywhere near final release and features could still be removed before it goes final.

Comment: what you consider *redundant*, is *essential* to the instantiating system. What if you´d declare your variable as `var`? Or with a base-class? Or an interface? In those cases the compiler can´t infer which type to instantiate. You can however use `var dict = new Dict<T, int>(...)`.

Comment: I will edit the question, which is not a question about actual C#, but possibilities of new features: which could be named "Inferred constructor call" ? Someone tolds me the discussion exists actually here @dotnet: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100

Answer (score 3):

The C# team acknowledge this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100) and they plan to remove extra noise when relevent.

In the specific case of Dictionary, you will have to wait until C#9.

> Dictionary Literals introduces a simpler syntax to create initialized Dictionary objects without having to specify either the Dictionary type name or the type parameters. The type parameters for the dictionary are inferred using the existing rules used for array type inference.

```
// C# 1..8    
var x = new Dictionary <string,int> () { { "foo", 4 }, { "bar", 5 }};   
// C# 9    
var x = ["foo":4, "bar": 5];
```

> This proposal makes the work with dictionaries in C# simpler and removing the redundant code. In addition, it is worth to mention that a similar dictionary-syntax is used in other programming languages like F# and Swift.

[source](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/candidate-features-for-c-sharp-9/)

Well no... I just read that the [dictionary literals issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/414) was **rejected**...

> We think there are a number of interesting use cases around initializing data, particularly for things like immutable dictionaries. We don't find the existing syntax for initializing a dictionary that onerous, nor do we see it as a frequent pattern in code that would benefit much from a language feature. We thing that the general area of initializing data should be looked at again after we do records and withers. But this proposal doesn't feel compelling.

Comment: Or even better until C#9 IMHO: `var x = new Dictionary <string,int> () { ["foo"] = 4, ["bar"] = 5 };`